# Optaplanner - Roster rule to have approximatly same working days for all employee

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

After seeing OptaPlanner manual and tutorials/lab works, I managed to create a roster such that each employee works at least 1 weekend.

This works flawlessly. However, I wanted to add a rule such that all employees have same number of working shift. How to write a rule for this?

My class list: Shift class contains shift time and employee object.

In DRL, I have to get a count of shifts for each employees and constraint them to same values. Is this possible?

Comment: The fairness score constraint section in the docs might help: https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#fairnessScoreConstraints

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand how to calculate the weight but I dont know the syntax in DRL. if I use, `Shift(employee = $employee)` I get only shift count of a employee and then, how can I sum them other employees shift?

Comment: @Selva were you able to find a solution to this?